# Deploying Umbraco 12 website using Umbraco Cloud

Tags: umbraco

I have an Umbraco 12 website running locally with personal HTML5, CSS, customisation etc, and would like to successfully deploy it via Umbraco Cloud.

I created a trial account on [www.s1.umbraco.io](http://www.s1.umbraco.io), created a project, cloned the project as per provided project URL [https://scm.umbraco.io/euwest01/{project-name-here}.git](https://scm.umbraco.io/euwest01/%7Bproject-name-here%7D.git) - replaced Properties, Umbraco, Views and wwwwroot folders with the same folders of my Umbraco 12 website running locally.

I can see in the https://scm.umbraco.io portal the changes have been rolled out, yet, when I go to backoffice it's completely blank, none of my pages are there etc plus when I go to the main index page I see a default webpage with "You're seeing this wonderful page because your website doesn't contain any published content yet."

Comment: I'd suggest contacting Umbraco support via the chat function that should be in the Umbraco Cloud "portal" - they're really nice people!

Comment: Did you check the production environment to make sure the page is there to show? In addition to pushing changes up via repository, you also need to queue items like content pages and media to transfer between environments. To do this, right click on the content and then "queue for transfer"